# electron-rebuild building wrong version of node-sqlite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

I am trying to get an Electron app up and running on a Windows 10 dev machine. I run `npm install` and it installs all the dependencies including `sqlite3`, `electron-prebuilt` and `electron-rebuild`.

I then run `electron-rebuild -w sqlite3 -p` to create the node-sqlite3 bindings and this successfully creates `electron-v1.4-win32-x64` bindings.

However when I run the electron app, it throws an error as it is expecting `electron-v1.2-win32-x64`. How do I force a build of 1.2, rather than 1.4 of the bindings? Alternatively, how do I get my electron app to use v1.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild/blob/master/src/cli.js#L9-L39), or by running `electron-rebuild --help`.

I believe you can supply the version of electron for which you want to rebuild by supplying the `--version` flag.

So for you:

```
electron-rebuild -w sqlite3 -p --version 1.2
```

Or

```
electron-rebuild -w sqlite3 -p -v 1.2
```

As for getting your electron app to use v1.4, I think it's just a matter of installing and using some variant of electron v1.4 to launch your application. Is your version of `electron-prebuilt` installing electron v1.2?