# cannot install better-sqlite3 with build-from-source because electron ABI mismatch

Tags: node.js, electron, npm-install, node-gyp, better-sqlite3

I want to update better-sqlite3 in my Electron App. Because of some lags between Nodejs, Electron and better-sqlit3 releases, I need to manually install better-sqlite3 with this command :

`npm install better-sqlite3@latest --build-from-source --sqlite3="$(pwd)/sqlite-amalgamation"`

I'm using Node.js v18.9.0, so the ABI number is 108, therefore the better-sqlite3 compilation shall produce node_module_version=108.

But, according to https://github.com/electron/releases, it looks like I can't get Electron releases with and ABI=108.

Then, I end up with this error :

> Failed to initialize Database ... : Error: The module '...node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/better_sqlite3.node'
> was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 108. This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 107. Please try re-compiling or re-installing the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).

Obviously, `npm rebuild` or `npm install` did not work. Neither following workarounds, since the better-sqlite3 has to be built a part, using node-gyp that depends on my Node version (with ABI=108).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131312/electron-rebuild-building-wrong-version-of-node-sqlite3

[Node - was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 51](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384591/node-was-compiled-against-a-different-node-js-version-using-node-module-versio)
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131312/electron-rebuild-building-wrong-version-of-node-sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384591/node-was-compiled-against-a-different-node-js-version-using-node-module-versio)

Using node module node-abi, I got below numbers. Furthermore, according to https://www.electronjs.org/releases/stable, Electron 20.0.0 depends on Node 16.15.0, which an even lower ABI number.

So, I would like to know, if there is any way to get an Electron build with the ABI I want? Or how to build Electron by myself ?
Thanks

```
109   electron   21.0.0-alpha.1
108   node   18.0.0
107   electron   20.0.0-alpha.1
106   electron   19.0.0-alpha.1
103   electron   18.0.0-alpha.1
102   node   17.0.0
101   electron   17.0.0-alpha.1
099   electron   16.0.0-alpha.1
098   electron   15.0.0-beta.7
097   electron   14.0.2
093   node   16.0.0
089   electron   15.0.0-alpha.1
089   electron   14.0.0-beta.1
089   electron   13.0.0-beta.2
088   node   15.0.0
087   electron   12.0.0-beta.1
085   electron   11.0.0-beta.11
083   node   14.0.0
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> cd better-sqlite3
> node-gyp rebuild --release --target=15.3.0  --dist-url=https://electronjs.org/headers
```

[electron version]
`[15.3.0,19.0.1] is ok`